# API Explorer inputs keep giving me authentication errors

Tags: docusignapi

[REST API EXPLORER](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHAPn.png)

All I'm trying to do is get some response on this basic API call.

On the Login_setting parameter I put either 'all or none and I still always get the response:

```
errorCode: "AUTHORIZATION_INVALID_TOKEN"
message:   "The access token provided is expired, revoked or malformed."
```

I don't know what to trouble shoot or if I should be putting something else in the parameter fields.

I also get this message:

```
message: "One or both of Username and Password are invalid. Invalid access token"
```

Same circumstances. What am I missing here? This is the "login" API call I'm testing with api explorer.

Comment: Did you create a free sandbox account and authenticate using that account in the api explorer?

Comment: yes, i created teh free sandbox account.  At the top of the api explorer, it shows that I am "Authenticated".  I think it shows this in the screen shot i provided.

Comment: Click Unauthenticate at the top and Authenticate again (use GET OAUTH2 TOKEN button on the popup screen) and check if it resolves your issue. AccessToken expires in 28800 secs, so might be your access token expired.

Comment: Holy Crap that worked!  Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

For benefit of community, looks like it's possible for stale auth data to hand around even though it appears you may be authenticated with the API Explorer tool.

To resolve simply click the "Unauthenticate" button then login again and you'll be able to start testing requests again.

For reference:  https://apiexplorer.docusign.com